# Competitive - Algorithm for max number of superior characters

Tags: algorithm, performance

I tried to solve this challenge some competitive website. here is the desc:

Given a string, a character is said to be superior if it has two neighboring letters that are strictly smaller than itself. We compare characters by their location in the alphabet.

More formally, we say that the character at the ith position is superior if a character exists at the (i+1)th position and (i-1)th position, and the character at the ith position is strictly greater than the character at both (i+1)thand (i-1)th positions.

Given the frequencies of the lowercase English letters, form a string using all these characters, such that the resultant string has the maximum number of superior characters. You need to print the maximum number of superior characters.

Complete the function maximumSuperiorCharacters which takes in an array of integers denoting the frequencies of the English letters and returns an integer denoting the maximum number of superior characters.

0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 we have two es, one l, one s, and none of the other letters. We can form a string with one superior character, for example, else. One can also show that this is the maximum number of superior characters that can be present. Thus, the answer is 1. There are also many other permutations of characters possible to form a string with maximum superior characters.

Here is what i done so far

```
int maximumSuperiorCharacters(int[] Q)
{
  int R = 0;
  for (int V : Q) R += V;
  return --R / 2;
}
```

Comment: What would your routine return for input data of `[7 0 0 ...]`, that is, just seven letters `'a'` allowed...?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: If it was solved, just accept an answer. No need to vandalise (or delete, I presume you tried that) your question. We like to keep content on the site, especially *solved* questions, since future readers might benefit from the Q/A.

Comment: This question is part of an ongoing competition (https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/w37/challenges/superior-characters). Please delete this post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in `O(N)` greedily. The maximum number of superior letters can be `M = floor((N-1)/2).` Start from the biggest letter and go `M` letters downhill. Say you finished at level `L`. Count number of letters at levels `0..L-1`, call it `S(0,L-1)`. 
Then you need to decrease number of letters taken from level `L` to `S(0,L-1)-1` and you are done.

Here i provide an implementation:

```cpp
int maxsup(const vector<int>& charsCount) {
    const int length = accumulate(charsCount.cbegin(), charsCount.cend(), 0);
    const int optMaxSup = (length - 1) / 2;

    int charsUpToLimitLevelCount = 0;
    int limitLevel = 0;
    for (; charsUpToLimitLevelCount <= length - optMaxSup && limitLevel < (int)charsCount.size(); ++limitLevel) {
        charsUpToLimitLevelCount += charsCount[limitLevel];
    }
    const int supAtLimitLevel = optMaxSup + charsUpToLimitLevelCount - length;
    charsUpToLimitLevelCount -= charsCount[--limitLevel];

    const int matchedSupCount = min(supAtLimitLevel, max(charsUpToLimitLevelCount - 1, 0));
    return optMaxSup - (supAtLimitLevel - matchedSupCount);
}


int main() {
    cout << maxsup({ 0,0,0,0,0 }) << endl;
    cout << maxsup({ 0,0,0,0,1 }) << endl;
    cout << maxsup({ 0,0,0,2,1 }) << endl;
    cout << maxsup({ 15,7,0,0,0 }) << endl;
    cout << maxsup({ 5,4,3,2,1 }) << endl; // aaaaabbbbcccdde -> abacacacadbdbeb - 7
                                           //                     1 2 3 4 5 6 7
}
```

The output is:

> 0
>   0
>   1
>   7
>   7

[Live.](http://rextester.com/HKNRRM29635)

Comment: How would that work for a set of N=seven letters `'a'`...? I understand M=3. We start with the biggest letter, which is `'a'` and go 3 letters downhill. We are still at `'a'`. What next?

Comment: @CiaPan thanks for the question, yeh, we stop at level `a` and next we check number of letters in the string below level `a`, there are zero such letters, so we decrease `M` to `M-3` which is zero.

Comment: try this {15,7,0,0,0} - correct answer should be - 7

Comment: @IgorJS thanks for the valuable test case! I updated the implementation and added live version to make tests easier. The idea still the same, that was a bug in the implementation:)

Comment: This passed in java. Thanks.

Comment: what is accumulate() ? is there same function in java?

Comment: @Kefhee11 `accumulate` returns sum of elements in a range. Here i use it to count the total number of characters in a string.

Comment: @Yola: What is supAtLimitLevel?

Comment: @Yola: what is matchedSupCount?

Comment: @Khafaga limit level is the level `L`, `supAtLimitLevel` is the number of superiors at this level we try to use at first, but it is not always possible to use all of them, so `matchedSupCount` is the actual number of superiors from the limit we can use.

Answer (score 1):

```
static long maximumSuperiorCharacters(int[] freq) {
    final int length = Arrays.stream(freq).sum();
    final int optMaxSup = (length - 1) / 2;

    int charsUpToLimitLevelCount = 0;
    int limitLevel = 0;
    for (; charsUpToLimitLevelCount <= length - optMaxSup && limitLevel < freq.length; ++limitLevel) {
        charsUpToLimitLevelCount += freq[limitLevel];
    }
    final int supAtLimitLevel = optMaxSup + charsUpToLimitLevelCount - length;
    charsUpToLimitLevelCount -= freq[--limitLevel];

    final int matchedSupCount = Math.min(supAtLimitLevel, Math.max(charsUpToLimitLevelCount - 1, 0));
    return optMaxSup - (supAtLimitLevel - matchedSupCount);

}
```